# Spectrum analyzer

Tags: spectrum-analyzer

Do we need to connect different frequency sine wave sources to spectrum analyzer? Or will spectrum analyzer supply different frequencies of sine wave source to the DUT? Could someone explain the basic operation of a spectrum analyzer? Does a spectrum analyzer just measure the "different frequency components" of a 10kHz sine wave source? That means the 10kHz sine wave composed of many different frequencies.

Comment: An entire book could be written on this topic.

Comment: I think you miss some fundamental understanding about composed wave forms. A sine wave is not composed, it is a sine wave, the most basic signal of all. Any other wave form is composed out of sine waves. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency_spectrum#Spectrum_analysis

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a large amount of information about how spectrum analysers work on the Internet.

Variations are possible, but a spectrum analyser usually acts like a tunable receiver that "sweeps" across a frequency range of interest and measures the amplitude of signals (or energy in a known impedance load) present.

A spectrum analyser can be combined with a compatible controlled frequency source to test a filter or similar. The frequency source is input to the filter and the analyser measures the output and controls the source so that the source and analyser track. A similar result can be obtained by using a flat wideband noise source as input.

- [Agilent / HP intro](http://cp.literature.agilent.com/litweb/pdf/5965-7920E.pdf) - 80 pages of slides - gotta be good for you.
- [Spectrum Analyzer article at Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectrum_analyzer)
- [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nFaRZKNeSFU) - Good introduction - use with a function generator.
- [Radio electronics tutorial](http://www.radio-electronics.com/info/t_and_m/spectrum_analyser/rf-analyzer-basics-tutorial.php)
- [Fundamentals](http://electronicdesign.com/test-amp-measurement/fundamentals-spectrum-analysis)
- [Basics - ECE UCSB article (PDF)](http://www.ece.ucsb.edu/~long/ece145a/spec_analyzer.pdf)
- [Tektronix  (The Masters<sup>TM</sup>)](http://www.tek.com/learning/spectrum-analyzer-tutorial/spectrum-analyzer-video) - 10 short video tutorials
- [Anritsu even!](http://www.naic.edu/~phil/hardware/Misc/anritsu/SpectrumAnalyzer_basis_of.pdf) - looks good
- [Tutorial from TestRF.com](http://testrf.com/2010/spectrum-analyzer-tutorial/)
- [Uncle Tom Cobbly & all ...](https://www.google.co.nz/search?q=spectrum+analyser+tutorial&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=bN5tU8WbMoWmkAWN-YGoBg&ved=0CAYQ_AUoAQ&biw=1920&bih=1075)